# How to disable auto sort on Pivot Tables?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Set pvtC = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=stageWs.Range("A1:L" & dataWsLastRow), _
                                Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)
                                
Set pvtT = pvtC.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=stageWs.Range("N1"), TableName:="Staging Area")

With pvtT
    .ColumnGrand = False
    .RowGrand = False
 
    .PivotFields("Depth, ft").Orientation = xlColumnField
    .PivotFields("Number").Orientation = xlRowField
    .PivotFields("Pr").Orientation = xlDataField
    .PivotFields("SW").Orientation = xlDataField
    
End With
```

How do I disable the auto sorting by ascending order? I want the pivot table to render the data as-is...Thanks!

Comment: just sort it by col/val you actually want.

Comment: Yeah, I don't really know how to write the auto sort code. All my attempts have led to errors. If anyone knows how, please respond. In the meantime, I sorted the data prior to creating the pivot table such that its no longer an issue...